# Prepopulating lookup field on flow

Tags: lookup, visual-flows, process-automation

I need some help with a flow which I have developed to create a survey (custom object) record. This flow is being launched from an action button on a party event custom object. The idea is to capture the feedback about the party event in the survey object.

When I click on the "Request for Feedback" action button on the Party Event custom object, the flow launches. How do I prepopulate the lookup field on the flow with the party event record? Without it, I am able to create the survey record with the following fields. 1) Surveyor Name, 2) Surveyor Email 3) Rating.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are talking about getting the recordid of the record from where you launched the flow you can simply create Variable like as below - Type: Variable, Name: recordId,Input/Output Type: Input Only and then use that variable

Comment: it would be helpful to use [edit] the flow elements in question